# Bad Access With UISearchBar in tableHeaderView iOS 7

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uisearchbar, exc-bad-access, ios7

I am attempting to use a UISearch bar in my UITableview's tableHeaderView. This searching functionality worked without issues on iOS 6, but since building against the 7.0 SDK I get a crash when tapping the search bar after returning from another view. The first time viewing the searching tableView, the search bar works just as expected. But once I drill into a detail view, the search bar throw an exc-bad-access exception when I tap it. This bad access is not logged by using NSZombies in my scheme. Here is the code to setup the header view:

```
    self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44)];
    self.searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc]
                             initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar contentsController:self];
    self.searchController.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    self.searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;
```

Properties `self.searchBar` and `self.searchController` are both declared as strong references. The no memory warnings are being received anywhere. Has something changed with UISearchBar or tableHeaderView in iOS 7? It may also be noteworthy that I am applying an appearance proxy to UISearchBar, but it looks and works correctly on first load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the crash was due to using `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView` along with a `UISearchDisplayController` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18918986/uitableview-section-index-related-crashes-under-ios-7/19010375#19010375)). This seems to be a bug in the iOS 7 SDK. Instead, I am now using [CMIndexBar](https://github.com/CraigMerchant/CMIndexBar) as a third party replacement. Works just like the native section indexes, never crashes, easily customizable.

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble with UISearchBar crashes in iOS7 until I started setting my UISearchDisplayController as inactive before the UITableViewController is dismissed.  Adding the following worked for me, but I don't know if our problems are related:

```
[_mySearchDisplayController setActive:NO];
```