# UITableView reloadData EXC_BAD_ACESS code=2

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, automatic-ref-counting, exc-bad-access

I have this code for loading the UITableView:

```
- (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if (tableView == self.peopleTableView)
        return [self.people count];
    else
        return [[[self.scheduleDays objectAtIndex:self.dayInt] periods] count];
}

- (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableView == self.peopleTableView)
        return [[self.people objectAtIndex:section] count];
    else
        return 1;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableView == self.peopleTableView)
        return [self.headers objectAtIndex:section];
    else
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", [[[[self.scheduleDays objectAtIndex:self.dayInt] periods] objectAtIndex:section] startTime], [[[[self.scheduleDays objectAtIndex:self.dayInt] periods] objectAtIndex:section] endTime]];
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return self.headers;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    return index;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (tableView == self.peopleTableView) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        if (cell == nil)
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

        Person *person = [[self.people objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        [[cell textLabel] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [person firstName], [person lastName]]];

        return cell;
    } else {
        ScheduleTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[ScheduleTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
            [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
        }

        Period *period = [[[[[[self appDelegate] user] scheduleDays] objectAtIndex:self.dayInt] periods] objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];

        [[cell mainLabel] setText:[period desc]];
        [[cell subtitleLabel1] setText:[period teacher]];
        [[cell subtitleLabel2] setText:[period roomLocation]];

        return cell;
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (tableView == self.peopleTableView) {
        self.currentViewedPerson = [[self.people objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        [self loadPerson:self.currentViewedPerson];
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (tableView == self.scheduleTable)
        return 70;
    else
        return 44;
}
```

I use the method call `[_tableView reloadData]` to load the data. It works fine the first time, but the second time it fails with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2`. Why?

**EDIT:**

It appears that the error is coming from a call to

```
#0  0x01b8c2a3 in TComponentFont::GetMinSideBearing(CGAffineTransform const&, bool) const ()
```

[image: TComponentFont]

or a call to

[image]

I hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

Also no help from NSZombies. Running it in Xcode (with NSZombies) I get the same error no output, profiling it with the zombies profile it comes up with no message, the app just crashes.

**EDIT:**

This error is coming from the section titles, as when I comment out those sections I no longer get the error. What is incorrect about my section titles implementation?

**EDIT:**

This is how `_headers` is declared in DirectoryViewController.h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *headers;
```

How headers is populated (probably not all necessary but...):

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    if (parser == self.peopleParser) {
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"People"]) {
            self.people = [NSMutableArray array];
            self.headers = [NSMutableArray array];
        } else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Person"]) {
            self.currentPerson = [Person new];
            [self.currentPerson setPersonID:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"id"]];
        }
    } else if (parser == self.scheduleParser) {
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Schedule"])
            self.scheduleDays = [NSMutableArray array];
        else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Day"]) {
            NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ScheduleDay" inManagedObjectContext:[[self appDelegate] managedObjectContext]];
            self.currentDay = [[ScheduleDay alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];
        } else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Course"]) {
            NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Period" inManagedObjectContext:[[self appDelegate] managedObjectContext]];
            self.currentPeriod = [[Period alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];
        }
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    self.currentString = string;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    if (parser == self.peopleParser) {
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"People"])
            self.currentLetter = @"";
        else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Person"]) {
            if ([self.currentLetter isEqualToString:[[[self.currentPerson lastName] substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString]])
                [[self.people lastObject] addObject:self.currentPerson];
            else {
                [self.people addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];
                [self.headers addObject:[[[self.currentPerson lastName] substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString]];
                self.currentLetter = [[[self.currentPerson lastName] substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString];
                [[self.people lastObject] addObject:self.currentPerson];
            }
        } else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Last"])
            [self.currentPerson setLastName:self.currentString];
        else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"First"])
            [self.currentPerson setFirstName:self.currentString];
        else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"EmailAddress"])
            [self.currentPerson setEmail:self.currentString];
        else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"PhoneCell"])
            [self.currentPerson setCellPhone:self.currentString];
        else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"PhoneHome"])
            [self.currentPerson setHomePhone:self.currentString];
        else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"GradYear"])
            [self.currentPerson setGradYear:self.currentString];
        else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"StudentGrade"])
            [self.currentPerson setGrade:self.currentString];
        else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Street1"])
            [self.currentPerson setStreet1:self.currentString];
        else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Street2"])
            [self.currentPerson setStreet2:self.currentString];
        else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"City"])
            [self.currentPerson setCity:self.currentString];
        else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"State"])
            [self.currentPerson setState:self.currentString];
        else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Zip"])
            [self.currentPerson setZip:self.currentString];
    } else if (parser == self.scheduleParser) {
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Course"])
            [self.currentPeriod setDay:self.currentDay];
        else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Day"])
            [self.scheduleDays addObject:self.currentDay];
        else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"StartTime"])
            [self.currentPeriod setStartTime:self.currentString];
        else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"EndTime"])
            [self.currentPeriod setEndTime:self.currentString];
        else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Description"])
            [self.currentPeriod setDesc:self.currentString];
        else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Location"])
            [self.currentPeriod setRoomLocation:self.currentString];
        else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Teacher"])
            [self.currentPeriod setTeacher:self.currentString];
    }
    self.currentString = @"";
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError {
    if ([parseError code] == 5) {
        self.people = [NSMutableArray array];
        self.headers = [NSMutableArray array];
    } else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!" message:[parseError description] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Where the `reloadData` is called:

```
- (void)search {
    NSString *urlString = [LINK SETUP CODE GOES HERE]

    self.peopleParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    self.peopleParser.delegate = self;
    if ([self.peopleParser parse] && [self.people count] > 0) {
        [self.peopleTableView reloadData];
        [self.peopleTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
        [self.view addSubview:self.peopleView];
    } else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Results!" message:@"Your search returned no results. Try broadening your search." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    self.activityIndicator.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: That error usually occurs because of trying to access a deallocated object. You should make sure all your objects, have strong pointers to them (like _people and _headers).

Comment: how you are allocating `_people`

Comment: @samfisher `_people = [NSMutableArray new];`

Comment: @rdelmar All objects have strong pointers

Comment: @samfisher I also tried `_people = [NSMutableArray array]` but I get the same error

Comment: if NSZombie did not tell you anything, maybe it is not retain/release problem. it can be dereference to null pointer (which is often in C++ code)

Comment: @BryanChen Thanks for your response. Is there anyway to check this or fix it?

Comment: what is `TComponentFont`? Xcode should be able to break on the line crashed if it can find the symbols/debug information.

Comment: @BryanChen This piece does not appear every time. But on the left panel debug navigator that sometimes is the top piece.

Comment: @BryanChen Please see the last edit. `TComponentFont` must be a call done when setting up the index side bar.

Comment: Are you using ARC? More code is needed to debug this. Where is _headers defined, and how, and how is it populated?

Comment: `[_headers indexOfObject:title];` make sure it does not return `NSNotFound`

Comment: @BryanChen I realized that line was unnecessary and I could just `return index`. I edited the question.

Comment: I would double check that numberOfSectionsInTableView can equally well return _headers.count. _headers.count should be the same as _people.count; if not, there's a parse error to debug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid memory issues you should create your objects and refer to your objects using property accessor methods.

For example you declare property for `headers` mutable array:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *headers;
```

Then you should create your array this way:

```
 self.headers = [NSMutableArray array];
```

And refer to your array this way:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.headers objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return self.headers;
}
```

Using this syntaxis you call setter and getter methods for `headers` property (these methods automatically generated by Xcode).

In non-ARC environment it is equivalent for calling these methods for `(retain, nonatomic)` property (`retain` is analog of `strong`):

```
- (NSMutableArray *)headers {

  return _headers;
 }

- (void)setHeaders:(NSMutableArray *)headers {

    [_headers autorelease];
    _headers = [headers retain];
}
```

If you use `self.` notation in ARC environment tracking of an object's reference count will be done automatically.

You can find more information about properties [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html).

**EDIT:**

It seems to be a bug in the framework. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19010375/1158590)

Comment: One quick last semi-related question. Is there a difference between accessing and setting the object via object.var and [object var]/[object setVar]. Or do both call the same methods?

Comment: Both variants are equal. Just old and new notation style.

Comment: It appears that I approved you answer prematurely. I hope you will still have interest after I have given you the 50 :). I tried this once, and it seemed to work, but now the problem is occurring again. I will edit the code in the question to reflect what I have now.

Comment: Try to set Exception Breakpoint to get more information about where your application crashes. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Also please provide more information about where and when you call reloadData.

Comment: I added the call to reloadData. The exception breakpoint did not do anything.

Comment: Try to call reloadData in parserDidEndDocument: delegate method.

Comment: I moved `reloadData` there and no difference. Still get the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error. Also I can uncomment the `sectionIndexTitles` and `sectionForSectionIndexTitle` methods and the code works perfectly  so I do not think it has to do with my call to `reloadData`.

Comment: It seems to be a bug in the framework. Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19010375/1158590

Comment: I will submit another bug report to apple to help increase it's importance. I will have to comment out those lines until this is fixed :(. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The second it is because due to autorelease ,you should check values using NSLog() and then you can find solution very easliy.Get each value on different stages or in different methods

Comment: Everything looks fine when NSLogging. I now get code=2 though instead of code=1, right during or after the array of sectionIndexTitles is returned. So I need to first convert NSMutableArray to NSArray because I thought it would auto cast and why would it work the first time and not the second?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your code, my guess is that while the strings are equivalent for the array of headers, you are not properly comparing them in sectionForIndexTitle.

Please remember that indexOfObject will only work if the pointers to the strings are exactly the same. Having two strings with the same value isn't necessarily enough.

For safety you might try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [_headers count]; ++i)
{
    if ([_headers[i] isEqualToString title])
    {
        return i;
    }
}
// error handling belongs here
```

But again, that's a guess given that we don't have clear insight into how _headers is constructed or what else is going on in your code.

Comment: Please see my last comments on the main question.

Comment: Returning index for sectionForSectionIndexTitle is not correct behavior, unless you are 100% sure that all letters are included in your list of sections. Instead, you need to compute the nearest similar section. For example, if your headers include "A" "C" and "F", when you are passed "D", you need to return either 1 or 2.

Comment: This list of indices is the list of headers so it may be done.

Answer (score -1):

I think this crash is due to the auto releasing of TableView object, '_people' array or '_headers' array. The first thing you have to do is the logging of its values to check whether it an already released object. 
If so you can use

```
  [_people retain];
```

or

```
  [_headers retain];
```

or

```
 [tableviewObject retain];
```

for avoiding the auto release.

Comment: The retain method is deprecated, please provide me with code that is not deprecated.

Comment: Also what exactly is causing the problem and why would autorelease not work in this scenario.