# One object in NSArray being deallocated

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I am writing an app using the [TWTSideMenuViewController](https://github.com/twotoasters/TWTSideMenuViewController) installed using cocoapods. For this I have a ViewController titled MenuViewController which has an array of all the individual content view controllers:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        _controllerArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil],
                            [[AboutMeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AboutMeViewController" bundle:nil],
                            [[ScheduleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ScheduleViewController" bundle:nil],
                            [[FoodViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FoodViewController" bundle:nil],
                            [[CalendarViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CalendarViewController" bundle:nil],
                            [[AthleticsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AthleticsViewController" bundle:nil],
                            [[DirectoryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DirectoryViewController" bundle:nil], nil];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I then set up the TWTSideMenuViewController with this code:

```
MenuViewController *menuViewController = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuViewController" bundle:nil];
TWTSideMenuViewController *twtSideMenuViewController = [[TWTSideMenuViewController alloc] initWithMenuViewController:menuViewController mainViewController:[[menuViewController controllerArray] objectAtIndex:0]];
twtSideMenuViewController.zoomScale = .5;
twtSideMenuViewController.edgeOffset = UIOffsetMake(-80, 0);
self.window.rootViewController = twtSideMenuViewController;
```

All of this works perfectly, however when I switch to a different content view (other than the default, home, and I try to go back to home I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. I can switch back and forth between any other content view controllers, as it appears the HomeViewController is the only one deallocated.

I have a feeling that this has to do with the fact that it is accessed in the setup code, but is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: is the `_controllerArray` a `strong` `@property` ?

Comment: enable NSZombie and what does it tell you?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor yes it is strong, nonatomic

Comment: @BryanChen The NSZombies message: "An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated 'HomeViewController' object (zombie) at address: 0x16dc8450."

Comment: do you have any `__unsafe_unretained` reference to `HomeViewController`?

Comment: @BryanChen I am not sure exactly what that means but I do not explicitly call any method with the keyword `__unsafe_unretained`.

Comment: are you using cocospod to install `TWTSideMenuViewController`? I think it is using ARC but its podspec does not say so, which may cause memory problem.

Comment: @BryanChen I am using cocoapods. Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: I think it is a bug in their podspec, you can create an issue on their github page

Comment: @BryanChen Because you seem to know ARC well could you take a look at an old ARC question I asked which seems to have gone dead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042323

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The podspec has been updated on GitHub specifying ARC.

For more info: https://github.com/twotoasters/TWTSideMenuViewController/pull/9

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare each view controller's object as strong and pass it to the array like

```
@property(strong,nonatomic) HomeViewController *home;



home = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil]
_controllerArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:home,aboutme....];
```

In your old code, class objects are not declared with **strong reference**. A strong referenced object would make **retain loop**. That means you will become the owner of this object.

But when you declare object as local, you dont have the strong reference on it. That means it will deallocated automatically after current execution loop complete. That's why your **HomeViewController** local object in the array getting deallocated and shows the error

Comment: This fixed my issue. Could you please explain why it did and why only the HomeViewController was being deallocated but none of the others were.

Comment: @manujmv This is not solving the root of the problem, this is a hack. Adding to the array is a "strong" reference as it will increase each view controllers retain count by 1. Bryan Chen is correct, if their pod spec does not specify ARC when ARC is implied, then TWTSideMenuViewController is doomed from the beginning.